# How insert one-to-one, one-to-many relationship using nodejs with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two collections in my database those are following

1. student
2. course

I want to insert data's like `one-to-one`, `one-to-many` relationship.

**example**

Am sent following data's in my `form-data`

1. name
2. email
3. phone
4. password
5. course_name
6. course_cost

The above data's `name`, `email`, `phone`, `password` stored in **student** table.

And `course_name`, `course_cost` stored to **course** table with `student_id`.

This is my code:

`route/students.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('../config/database');


const router = express.Router();

let Student = require('../models/student_model');

router.post('/add_student', function(req, res){
    let data = new Student();
    data.name = req.body.name;
    data.email = req.body.email;
    data.phone = req.body.phone;
    data.password = req.body.password;

    data.save(function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(data);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

`models/student_model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let StudentSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    email:{
        type: String
    },
    phone:{
        type: String
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    },

    }, { collection: 'student' });


const Student = module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

This is my API call:
[image]

> My above code am done store student data stored in `student` table, but i don't know how to add one-to-one relationship

Comment: Did you have `course` schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to redesign the schema. Considering you have two different collections for student and course, you need a reference of course in student and student reference in course collection. This will help you to execute following kind of queries.

1. Get list of courses for student x.
2. Get a list of students who have enrolled for course ABC.
   Add courses array in student schema and students array in courses schema. 
   Check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

In your route you request name,  email,  phone,  password. Then you try insert course_name,  course_cost. You need to insert student_id in course collection

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, however, i believe many people may be looking for a solution to this similar schema relation design. You need to declare a One to Many schema relation in your Model.

```
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    password: String,
    course: [courseSchema] //this will be the relationship
})
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
    course_name: String, 
    course_cost: String
})

const Student = mongoose.model('student', StudentSchema)

module.export = Student;
```